# Can a covering map from a neighborhood be extended to the whole space?

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups, covering-spaces

**Edit:** from now on please assume $H=SL(2,\mathbb R), X=PSL(2,\mathbb R)$

I'm dealing with a topological group (assume some "good" group if needed, perhaps a lie group. But do **not** assume compact group, despite the fact that it should make everything here rather easy) $G$ which is locally isomorphic to some group $H$. Say I can find a covering map $p:H\to X$ for some topological space $X$.Can I derive a covering map $q:G\to X$?

The idea that makes it reasonable for me is that for every $x\in G$ we can take a neighborhood $U_x$ which is isomorphic to $H$ and define $q|_{U_x}=p$. I think that still for every $x\in X$ the pre-image would satisfy the demands of a covering map, but the main problem with my idea is the well-defined and continuity of $q$.

Another idea is to assume local compactness of $G$ (which is fine by me), and maybe (I can't see that clearly) that $G$ is a finite disjoint union of copies of $H$ (which seems quite strong and probably wrong).

Comment: The Lie groups $H={\mathbb R}$ and $G={\mathbb S}^1$ are locally isomorphic.  The identity is a covering map $H\to H$. Now, think: Is there a covering map $G\to H$? Another example to consider is $H=SU(2), G=SO(3), X=H$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen thank you very much. This makes sense. Is there something special to be said for H=SL(2,R) and X=PSL(2,R)?